# Removing symbolic links for a original file in C

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am writing a C program, that uses *NIX System calls. Now, when the user calls for deleting a particular file, I want to remove all the symbolic links created to the file, also to be removed. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the symbolic links? It is legitimate to keep them! (and the user could recreate the file by writing on them)

Comment: As per  the problem description, I need to simulate a cloud storage, where a user share can share a file to another user. so when the original file is deleted, wouldn't that be nice to remove the symbolic links

Comment: No, it is not nice and it would be wrong. Your user is using symbolic links for their usual behavior. Leave him the responsibility and the freedom of dangling symlinks. It is his system (so he, not you, should administer it), not yours!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to get a list of symbolic links that point to a particular file save 'the hard way', IE go through the entire file system recursively (or whatever subset of the file system you know the symbolic links to be in) and determine whether any resolve to that file. You would probably be best outsourcing that to the `find` utility.

Comment: Is it possible to know,the number of links to that file, or atleast, whether symbolic link exists or not?

Comment: No. You can tell the number of hard links to the inode though. That won't tell you anything about symbolic (soft) links.

Comment: Symbolic links can also exist in other filesystems, so you must also scan other mounted filesystems, and perhaps unmounted filesystems that were mounted at some point.

Answer (score 5):

You can't, unless you search the whole directory tree, or you have some other means of knowing where these symbolic links are. A file doesn't "know" which symlinks point to it. You have to locate each symlink on your own and `unlink()` it.